# On simple extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Show that $\mathbb{R}$
  is not a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$
  as follow:

a. $\mathbb{Q}$
  is countable.

b. Any simple extension of a countable field is countable.

c. $\mathbb{R}$
  is not countable.

I 've done a. and c. Can anyone help me a hint to prove b.?

Comment: **Hint:** A simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ would be the image of an evaluation homomorphism on $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, univariate polynomials with rational coefficients.  How big can it be?

Comment: @hardmath: Don’t you have to go to $\Bbb Q(X)$ if it’s a transcendental extension?

Comment: Actually the above applies to a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a ring.  Perhaps the problem is intended to deal with a simple extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a field, and the approach should be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be a countable field, then the collection of all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ is countable. Hence, $F[x]$ is countable, being the countable union of countable sets. Hence, $F[x] \times F[x]\setminus\{0\}$ is countable. There is a surjective function $F[x]\times F[x]\setminus\{0\} \to F(x)$ by
$$
(f(x), g(x)) \mapsto \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
Hence, $F(x)$ is countable. If $a$ is transcendental over $F$, then $F(x) \cong F(a)$, which is thus countable.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify things let us divide in two cases:

**The extension of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is algebraic:** Then we have $\;\Bbb Q(\alpha)/\Bbb Q\;$  of degree $\;n\;$ , and every element in the extension is of the form $\;a_0+a_1\alpha+\ldots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb Q\;$ ...

**The extension of $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is transcendental:** Then $\;\Bbb Q(\omega)/\Bbb Q\;$ isn't finite, but in fact $\;\Bbb Q(\omega)\;$ is the fractions field of $\;\Bbb Q[\omega]\cong\Bbb Q[x]=\;$the polynomial ring in one variable over the rationals, and then we're almost done since

$$\left|\Bbb Q(\omega)\right|:=\left|\left\{\frac ab\;;\;a,b\in\Bbb Q[\omega]\;,\;b\neq 0\right\}\right|\le\left|\Bbb Q[x]\times\Bbb Q[x]\right|=\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\aleph_0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **hint**: Let $F$ be a countable field, $F(a)$ a simple extension. Then every element in $F(a)$ can be written as a quotient $\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials. Now, combine known results on countability.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain more precisely to me?